# If one of the terms of a geometric progression is $0$, can it be a valid GP?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Since anything divided by zero is not defined, is the geometric progression, having one of its terms as $0$, a valid GP?

Comment: If one term in a geometric progression is zero, all must be zero.

Comment: ... or the first one is whatever and all the others are $0$.

Comment: Technically $0,0,0,0,\ldots$ is a geometric progression (as @SeanRoberson points out), but that is the only one containing $0$, and is quite trivial and should be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply anything by zero it equals zero so if the first term of a GP is zero all the terms will be zero. I wouldn't call that a very interesting GP... a trivial GP might be a suitable name.